# What is the difference between "logging monitor" and "terminal monitor" commands?

Tags: syslog

I'm currently studying Syslog for CCNA and the course I use mentioned the following command that configures logging of messages to vty lines.

*logging monitor level*

However, it was then mentioned that even if this command is used, by default Syslog messages are not displayed when we are connected to the device via VTY lines. In order for the messages to be displayed, we need to use the

*terminal monitor* cmd

whenever we connect to the device using VTY lines.

I'm a bit confused about this. What exactly is the difference between these 2 commands and their purpose? To me, they look like they perform the same function. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`logging monitor <level>` determines what syslog priority level will be logged.

When you connect to a router via VTY, syslog messages are not displayed unless you issue the `terminal monitor` command.

Answer (score 0):

The command below shows which type of connection and what level of logs I will keep.

R1#show logging | inc level

Console logging: level debugging,

***Monitor logging: level debugging**,*

Buffer logging: level debugging,

Trap logging: level informational,

You can set this level with the ***logging monitor level*** command and you decide whether to log or not with the ***terminal monitor*** command.